# joins in sql giving me weird results

Tags: sql, join

I have two queries, Q1 and Q2.

Q1 produces one result for each demo and date.

Q2 produces one result for each demo, date and site.

Also, the dates for a given demo and site from Q2 will have some overlap with Q1,

but all dates from Q1 won't be there and there might even be some new dates in Q2 that were not there in Q1.

What I want to do is produce a resulting table that has the results of Q1 basically repeated (rows beneath rows) equal to the number of sites in Q2.

And the results from Q2 should be in the second column with a match on the date and demo.

If a date in Q1 doesn't exist in that site of Q2, the entry should be zero or null. I know this can be achieved with joins, but I can't get it to work. I tried -

```
select a.result, b.site, b.result from
(Q1) as a right join (Q2) as b on a.demo = b.demo and a.date=b.date
```

but this is producing some weird results. The entries of a.result are different for each site of Q2 though they shouldn't be.

edit - here is what I'm trying to do -

Q1 -

```
demo    |   date
------------------------------
1       |   10/31/2013
1       |   11/01/2013
2       |   11/02/2013
```

Q2 -

```
 demo   |   site    |   date
------------------------------
1       |   A       |   10/31/2013
1       |   A       |   11/01/2013
2       |   B       |   11/01/2013
2       |   B       |   11/02/2013
```

desired result -

```
    demo    |   date          | site
---------------------------------------
   1        |   10/31/2013    |  A
   1        |   11/01/2013    |  A
   2        |   11/02/2013    |  null
   1        |   10/31/2013    |  null
   1        |   11/01/2013    |  B
   2        |   11/02/2013    |  B
```

Comment: I didnt understood everything your written but i fell like you should try to use `left join` instead.

Comment: Can you add some sample input and output? And also your dbms?

Comment: It's a bit hard to understand, you could do with posting the results (sample data) produced by Q1 & Q2, along with the results you want to get.

Comment: Sorry for the delay guys, I was trying to work out how tables work in SO. Jacob's answer helped me. I've now described what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Use inner join instead of right join

```
select a.result, b.site, b.result from (Q1) as a 
inner join (Q2) as b on a.demo = b.demo and a.date=b.date
```

Comment: Thanks Low.. see my edit.. this query doesn't produce the nulls required.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarification, you could get that result with this query.

```
SELECT
    a.demo,
    a.date,
    b.site
FROM (Q1) a
LEFT JOIN (Q2) a ON b.date = a.date
```

Sorting it as you have in your result list would require more information in the subqueries, however.  You'd need to use a function like Row_Number() (assuming you're using MSSQL) to generate unique IDs in the sub-queries to use for sorting.

Comment: Thanks Jacob, but that is not quite what I'm trying to do.. see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98cafb/4/0) example of what I think you are asking for:

```
SELECT M.demo, M.date, M.site FROM
(
  SELECT 2 AS FromQuery, Q2.demo, Q2.date, Q2.site
  FROM Q2
  UNION
  SELECT 1 AS FromQuery, Q1.demo, Q1.date, null AS site
  FROM Q1
) AS M
ORDER BY M.FromQuery
```